# Dockerfile CMD not running automatically during container run time, but the command works when run inside the container

Tags: dockerfile, ioc-container

```
 #My Dockerfile
    
    FROM ubuntu
    
    RUN apt-get update
    
    RUN echo 8 4 |apt-get install -y nginx
    
    COPY ./index.html ./var/www/html/
    
    COPY ./nginxstart.sh ./usr/sbin/nginxstart.sh
    
    RUN chmod 755 /usr/sbin/nginxstart.sh
    
    CMD ["/usr/sbin/nginxstart.sh"]
```

Dockerfile CMD not running automatically during container run time, but the command works when run inside the container

Comment: # ps -ef
UID          PID    PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root           1       0  0 17:17 pts/0    00:00:00 sh
root           6       1  0 17:18 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -ef